# Word VBA: Choose template from Dialog for a new Document

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

My macro will create a new document based on an existing template:

```
   Documents.Add Template:=strTemplateName, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
```

I'd like the user to be able to select the template "strTemplateName" from a dialog box, but I'm not even sure if you can capture its name with the Dialogs property. And would you use wdDialogToolsTemplates or wdDialogFileOpen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to answer your second question,

> would you use wdDialogToolsTemplates or wdDialogFileOpen?

Is to simply try both and see which one suits you better.  Good old fashioned trial and error FTW :)

I don't think the *either* is what you want, actually. I would probably just use a normal `FileDialog` dialog.

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim dialog As FileDialog
Dim strTemplateName as String

Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
dialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
dialog.Show
If dialog.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
    strTemplateName = dialog.SelectedItems(1)
Else:
    MsgBox "no file selected!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If


Documents.Add Template:=strTemplateName, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I should have made it clear that I don't really understand Dialogs, which is why trial and error wasn't working for me. But your other solution is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I don't know Word VBA very well -- actually I did this answer from trial & error :) I could see that neither of those allowed any sort of return value and I knew from other applications that there are `FileDialogs` which *do* allow return values. It seems like those `Application.Dialogs` are not input methods, but they could be used for something else; i.e., to allow the user to make some changes, perform some actions, etc., while the macro program is running.